# How to copy page from one docx to another in java

Tags: java, ms-word, automation, document, docx4j

I am trying to automate docx report generation process. For this I am using java and docx4j. I have a template document containing only single page.I would like to copy that page modify it and save it in another docx document.The output report is of multiple similar pages with modification from the template. How do I go about it.

PS : java and docx4j are my first choice but I am open to solutions apart from java and docx4j.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving it up to you to modify the template, here is how you could add one document to the end of another document. Suppose `base.docx` contains "This is the base document." and `template.docx` contains "The time is:", then after executing this code:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage doc = Docx4J.load(new File("base.docx"));
WordprocessingMLPackage template = Docx4J.load(new File("template.docx"));
MainDocumentPart main = doc.getMainDocumentPart();

Br pageBreak = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createBr();
pageBreak.setType(STBrType.PAGE);
main.addObject(pageBreak);

for (Object obj : template.getMainDocumentPart().getContent()) {
    main.addObject(obj);
}
main.addParagraphOfText(LocalDateTime.now().toString());

doc.save(new File("result.docx"));
```

Then `result.docx` will contain something like:

```
This is the base document.

^L

The time is:
2018-04-16T17:37:13.541984200
```

(Where ^L represents a page break.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the above code. However my new document was blank. To be more precise my original template is containing only header and some styling component. And I create a new base document using `WordprocessingMLPackage report = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();`

Comment: I also tried adding some content in the template (ie some paragraphs) and I am able to copy those in base document. However I would also like to copy header and styling (like page borders) from the template to base document, which currently using above code I am unable to do.

Comment: To get that content, you could clone the original docx as your starting point.  Or for copying complex content, you could consider Plutext's commercial Docx4j Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

> To be more precise my original template is containing only header and some styling component.

This kind of information can be stored in a Word stylesheet (.dotx file).

> PS : java and docx4j are my first choice but I am open to solutions apart from java and docx4j.

A good tool would be [pxDoc](https://www.pxdoc.fr): you can specify a dedicated stylesheet in your document generator, or use "variable styles"and specify the stylesheet only when you launch the document generation